# Excel VBA code affects screen even then not executed... - help needed

Tags: excel, vba

I have this sub in Excel's "ThisWorkbook":

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    On Error GoTo errore
    
    If Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 4) = "CALC" Then
    
        
        If Uscita = False Then
        
            ScreenUpdateOnOff (False)
 

            Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False

            With ActiveWindow
                .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
                .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True
            End With
 
            If CreazioneConfrontoSomme = False Then ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:=" "
    
            ScreenUpdateOnOff (True)
                
                
        Else
                
            MsgBox "Running here!"
            
            ScreenUpdateOnOff (False)
 
            Call DeleteSheet("CONFRONTO SOMME")
               
            With ActiveWindow
                .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
                .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True
            End With
 
                
            If Application.Workbooks.Count <= 1 Then
 
                ScreenUpdateOnOff (False)
                
                Massimizza_Ribbon
 
                Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
        
                ScreenUpdateOnOff (True)
                
            End If
    
        End If
    End If
    
errore:
End Sub
```

I have Excel 2010 and 2019 and in both cases this part of the code causes a brief "flickering" of the upper part of the screen:

```
            If Application.Workbooks.Count <= 1 Then
 
                ScreenUpdateOnOff (False)
                
                Massimizza_Ribbon
 
                Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
        
                ScreenUpdateOnOff (True)
                
            End If
```

EVEN WHEN IT'S NOT EXECUTED! (The variable "Uscita" is false unless I close the workbook and MsgBox "Running here!" in fact doesn't run).

If I delete or rem the code, the flickering disappears.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: What is `ScreenUpdateOnOff`?  There is `Application.ScreenUpdating = False or True`

Comment: Well I don't know what `ScreenUpdateOnOf` is. In Excel you use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` (or `True` to turn back on). Also how does `Uscita` become `True`? There isn't anything that sets it in this code? You've either misunderstood how variables work or you've taken this code from somewhere else without the correct context.

Comment: Remove the `On Error GoTo` line as well. There are use cases for this, but when you are trying to debug it's completely counter productive

Comment: @DarrellH I wrote the Sub ScreenUpdateOnOff because I have dozens of Application.ScreenUpdating = False or True and sometimes the behaviour wasn't the expected one.

Comment: @Simon The variable Uscita becomes true in Private Sub Workbook_beforeclose. It's needed to take care of some user's actions.

Comment: @urdearboy I tried, but nothing changes. For now I removed the code that makes the screen "flicker" upon opening the file. What is beyond my understanding is why this is happening!

Comment: I don't see where you are benefiting from `ScreenUpdateOnOff` and it is most likely causing your flickering.  It is still one line of code `Application.ScreenUpdating`